# Unknow keyword in configuration file

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb

I think the configuration of isolinux.cfg is wrong.. 
I tried every solution here on " ask! " but all failed for me..

I'm trying to install the ubuntu 14 with usb boot, i already got the iso file from ubuntu officil website, and the universal usb linux installer

[image]

Comment: Try another USB creator, like UNetbootin, or a different version of Universal USB Installer.

Comment: And check the md5sum of the iso. If this s a custom iso, post the  isolinux.cfg

Comment: That's not just an "unknown keyword", it looks like binary jibberish; something's gone wrong. +1 to re-create the USB, maybe with a different tool, & check md5 of iso

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fix an error which should not exist, better to check the [Ubuntu Official hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) and to download the `.iso` file again.

This will be much easier and more robust then trying to fix it yourself and then finding something else somewhere else went wrong as well.  **;-)**